# Python - Flask - Google-api - Error al abrir socket

Tags: python, flask, google-drive

Estoy con algunos problemas con Flask al utilizar librerías que integren a la API de Google Drive.

Tengo errores cuando `socket.io` existe; es un proyecto que ya funcionó en otros entornos pero Flask se comporta muy raro.

Por ejemplo, cada vez que ejecuto Flask sin socket IO se lee algo así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí comparto la configuración local de red:

```
ipconfig /all
Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Wi-Fi:
Sufijo DNS específico para la conexión. . :
Descripción . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek 8821CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
Dirección física. . . . . . . . . . . . . : F8:08:4F:4C:99:70
DHCP habilitado . . . . . . . . . . . . . : sí
Configuración automática habilitada . . . : sí
Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.127.2(Preferido)
Máscara de subred . . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Puerta de enlace predeterminada . . . . . : 92.168.127.1
Servidor DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 92.168.127.1
Servidores DNS. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
NetBIOS sobre TCP/IP. . . . . . . . . . . : habilitado
```

¿Cómo seguir?

Comment: Bienvenida/o a [es.so]: lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y coloca el mensaje de error _como texto, con formato_, ya que [no todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Además, haz el que el título de la pregunta también sea descriptivo.